# How do I deploy a function app from VS2017 without a generated function.json?

Tags: azure-functions

When I deploy my Function App it shows a message in the portal

```
Your app is currently in read-only mode because you have 
published a generated function.json. 
Changes made to function.json will not be honored by the Functions runtime
```

With a [link to this topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#conversion-to-functionjson) which points out that function.json is not meant to be "edited directly"

I know how to enable the function to run in Azure via [these instructions](https://jaredrhodes.com/2017/11/13/your-app-is-currently-in-read-only-mode-because-you-have-published-a-generated-function-json/)

However when I re-publish my function from Visual Studio the Read Only problem re-occurs.

How do I prevent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are publishing your function app from VS, you really should not try to stop it from generating function.json, or try to to modify it after it gets generated. This simply will not work correctly when you are dealing with a compiled .NET Function App.

So instead of asking yourself how you can get around this, you need to step back and focus when what actual problem you are trying to solve, which almost certainly has a solution which doesn't involve trying to mess with function.json.

To put it another way, when deploying via VS, you do not even need to be aware of that fact that there is a function.json. It's an implementation detail, and you will never deal with this file directly.

Comment: it turns out that a read only function will run but the button takes a while to become enabled.

Answer (score 1):

This used to be a bug earlier, and [the link you mentioned](https://jaredrhodes.com/2017/11/13/your-app-is-currently-in-read-only-mode-because-you-have-published-a-generated-function-json/) was a work around.

This bug has been fixed a while back, so you should be able to set the "[FUNCTION_APP_EDIT_MODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#functionappeditmode)" to "readwrite" and even VS generated function should respect that App Settings flag.

So the problem might be that your setting is currently "readonly" or not set at all, in which case it might be defaulting to "readonly". Try setting it to "readwrite" and hopefully that should fix the behavior you see.

Look at these bug related documentation links on github.

[VS generated functions can become read/write #1971](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-ux/pull/1971)

[ReadOnly because function.json was auto generated should respect the read\write flag #1913](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-ux/issues/1913)

You can even see the code that was changed for it :)

[Code Changes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-ux/pull/1971/files/7ae223e21599decdc64ac4d6af7489527e5eb826)

Comment: thanks, where do I find "FUNCTION_APP_EDIT_MODE" settings flag ?

Comment: I added     "FUNCTION_APP_EDIT_MODE":  "readwrite" to local.settings.json but it did not help

Comment: @KirstenGreed local.settings.js will only take effect in local dev environment. You will need to update the setting in Azure Portal and post the bug fix I mention above, VS deployment will respect the current readwrite state of your function and not make it readonly

Comment: I found it is possible to set in VS on the publish tab "Manage Application Settings"

Comment: ok makes sense. Try it out and it should not be overwritten in further deployments.

Answer (score 0):

Both these answers helped me to find out that I should use the Manage Applications Settings link on the project publish tab. This becomes visible when I right click the project and select publish.